# R Studio/AWS Memory Requirements

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am studying the bike/scooter trip behavior of commuters in major cities and I am trying to collect real time data from an API every 15 seconds or so about the location of bike/scooter sharing devices.

Here is an example API of the data:

https://data.lime.bike/api/partners/v1/gbfs/arlington/free_bike_status

I am using Rstudio/AWS to collect this data. I have two potential options and I am trying my best to minimize the cost of collecting because AWS is expensive and I am just a graduate student

1) Keep the memory low on AWS t.micro (1 GB) and save the output file into S3 repeatedly

or

2) Save a final file once daily but use a lot of memory for the instance.

What is the cost efficient way to collect this data? Is there a way R can tell me how GB of memory a data frame is taking up so I can adjust my AWS instance memory appropriately?

Comment: you can use `pryr::mem_used()` to see how much memory is used by the current session, or `pryr::mem_change(<<some-r-code>>)` to see how much memory gets used by running a piece of code.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to check memory without installing a package? That also takes memory. I want to check how much memory a dataframe takes up on the EC2 instance.

Comment: ya there probably is (since pryr is built on top of base R), but installing a package wont use RAM after you restart the session — loading it will use a negligible amount, def not enough to make a difference. storage space is a different issue but pryr is lightweight so i doubt if it matters. could consider using a lighter-weight data structure than a df too maybe